# Can a Project Startup Checklist be part of a Sprint Backlog?

Tags: agile, planning, sprint-backlog, initiation

Can "Project Startup Checklist" be a Sprint Backlog for product planning,which is event planning for my project? I have made "Identifying Project Startup Checklist" as a Sprint Backlog item for event planning as shown below:

[image: A table highklighting "Discuss event requirements" as a task within the "Identifying Project Startup Checklist" user story.]

Can developing a project startup checklist be a Sprint Backlog item for event planning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned, the backlog should comprise *items that will generate value*.

It doesn't mean that the team doesn't need *other governance activities*. You won't add into Sprint backlog "budget / cost management", "people management" (interviews, promotions) and other work. They have to happen, just not as part of the Sprint.

With that said, I'd assume you may be falling into a X>Y problem, by trying to start "using Agile", applying a framework (Scrum) for a set of activities that are usually used on more prescriptive methodologies / guides (PMBoK / PRINCE2, for instance). This is reinforced by the estimation in hours for each activity.

Also, based on other activities listed (such as set budget / assign roles) you may not even have a stablished Scrum team yet.

Being pragmatic (and potentially counter intuitive), I'd suggest you to stick to a checklist of (a minimal set of) activities that must happen *before you can create your first incremental*, regardless of framework. This is because you may be wasting time trying to apply a framework for the sake of using a framework when a checklist (with specific deadlines) could do the trick. While doing so (and assuming the stakeholders are onboarding into agile practices) I'd focus the efforts on understanding what's minimally required to validate the hypothesis (i.e. the MVP). And then you work *backwards*.

Answer (score 0):

In Scrum, each Sprint is "where ideas are turned into value". Every Sprint results, minimally, in a usable and potentially releasable product Increment. The Sprint Backlog is a plan, created and maintained by the Developers for the Developers, on how to make their next Increment and consists of the Sprint Goal, a set of selected Product Backlog Items, and an actionable plan. Product Backlog Items are things that improve the product.

Most of items in this Project Startup Checklist seem to be things that the team should do prior to the very first Sprint and then reevaluated at other Scrum Events. For example, identifying constraints and potential solutions is a good topic for Sprint Review and Product Backlog refinement. Verifying the status of the budget is also a good topic for discussion at Sprint Review. Other items, like creating a work breakdown structure or creating a schedule for completion, are unnecessary for Scrum Teams.

Since none of the items on the Project Startup Checklist relate to improving the product, I wouldn't expect to see them on the Sprint Backlog as part of either the selected Product Backlog Items or the team's actionable plan. I would still expect to see some of these activities done, but at various Scrum events held throughout the Sprint.

Answer (score 0):

This is more for the program backlog which has a different workflow as your project hasn't been signed off yet. Have a look at [Program and solution backlogs according to SAFe](https://www.scaledagileframework.com/program-and-solution-backlogs/)

At this stage you don't want to clutter the team backlog with all that project initiation stuff as you might end up with a bunch of things that never get done.

You can consider this an epic and manage it as detailed here [Epics according to SAFe](https://www.scaledagileframework.com/program-and-solution-backlogs/)

Hope that helps ...